# Github Actions : pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: docker, yaml, github-actions, pyodbc, unixodbc

I  am on windows11 and I have created an API with django and venv. My API deploys a time series model. For the database, I don't have a script to initialize the database, my database comes from an external DB with Microsoft SQL Manager, I am connected to this database using pyodbc! Here is the file with which I connect to the database:

```
import pyodbc
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

def connect_to_database():
    db_server = os.environ.get('DB_SERVER')
    db_name = os.environ.get('DB_NAME')
    db_user = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
    db_password = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD')
    db_encrypt = os.environ.get('DB_ENCRYPT')
    db_trusted_connection = os.environ.get('DB_TRUSTED_CONNECTION')
    db_driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        DRIVER=db_driver,
        SERVER = db_server,
        DATABASE = db_name,
        ENCRYPT = db_encrypt,
        UID = db_user,
        PWD = db_password,
        Trusted_Connection = db_trusted_connection)

    return conn
```

And here is my Dockerfile :

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Set environment variables
ENV SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY \
    DEBUG=$DEBUG \
    ALLOWED_HOSTS_1=$ALLOWED_HOSTS_1 \
    ALLOWED_HOSTS_2=$ALLOWED_HOSTS_2 \
    AGENCY_1=$AGENCY_1\
    DB_SERVER=$DB_SERVER \
    DB_NAME=$DB_NAME \
    DB_USER=$DB_USER \
    DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD \
    DB_ENCRYPT=$DB_ENCRYPT \
    DB_TRUSTED_CONNECTION=$DB_TRUSTED_CONNECTION

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
# installation de unixodbc-dev
# Install SQL Server ODBC driver
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    gcc \
    gnupg2 \
    curl && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17=17.7.2.1-1 \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools \
    && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Install pyodbc
RUN pip install pyodbc

# Expose the port for the application
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the command to start the API
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

And that is my YAML:

```
name: CI/CD

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Compose
        run: |
          sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
          curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
          sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        env:
          DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
          SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
          DEBUG: ${{ secrets.DEBUG }}
          ALLOWED_HOSTS_1: ${{ secrets.ALLOWED_HOSTS_1 }}
          ALLOWED_HOSTS_2: ${{ secrets.ALLOWED_HOSTS_2 }}
          AGENCY_1: ${{ secrets.AGENCY_1 }}
          DB_SERVER: ${{ secrets.DB_SERVER }}
          DB_NAME: ${{ secrets.DB_NAME }}
          DB_USER: ${{ secrets.DB_USER }}
          DB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
          DB_ENCRYPT: ${{ secrets.DB_ENCRYPT }}
          DB_TRUSTED_CONNECTION: ${{ secrets.DB_TRUSTED_CONNECTION }}
        run: |
          docker build -t $DOCKER_USERNAME/my_image:latest .
          echo $DOCKER_PASSWORD | docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME --password-stdin
          docker push $DOCKER_USERNAME/my_image:latest

  test:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: 3.9

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Run tests
        env:
            DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
            DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
            SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
            DEBUG: ${{ secrets.DEBUG }}
            ALLOWED_HOSTS_1: ${{ secrets.ALLOWED_HOSTS_1 }}
            ALLOWED_HOSTS_2: ${{ secrets.ALLOWED_HOSTS_2 }}
            AGENCY_1: ${{ secrets.AGENCY_1 }}
            DB_SERVER: ${{ secrets.DB_SERVER }}
            DB_NAME: ${{ secrets.DB_NAME }}
            DB_USER: ${{ secrets.DB_USER }}
            DB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
            DB_ENCRYPT: ${{ secrets.DB_ENCRYPT }}
            DB_TRUSTED_CONNECTION: ${{ secrets.DB_TRUSTED_CONNECTION }}
        run: coverage run -m pytest  -v -s
  
      - name: Generate Coverage Report  
        run: coverage report -m
```

When I deploy my api on github, the build goes very well, but the problem is in the test to pass the unit tests. Github Actions gives me this error:

`pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Jobs are run into different runners. Building in under one job and using its build artifacts don't work automatically. You'll have to upload from first job and download in second to use that. In your case, it's much better to combine both jobs. After build, you can run tests in the job.

Comment: @Azeem. First of all thank you for your answer. I did what you suggested, but unfortunately I still get the same error. Do you have any other advice for me? Thank you

Comment: Where is your database server configured?